# NameError: name '' is not defined only in debug mode

Tags: python, pycharm, nameerror

I wrote python script, I changed one of the variable name, the code works fine, but when I ran it in debug mode i'm keep gets NameError on the variable that his name was changed, I tried to 'cleanup' the code and also did synchronize but it still happens. 
'time' was called 'timeNow' and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 1157, in do_it
     result = pydevd_vars.evaluate_expression(self.thread_id, 
self.frame_id, self.expression, self.doExec)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_vars.py", line 345, in evaluate_expression
Exec(expression, updated_globals, frame.f_locals)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.1\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'timeNow' is not defined
```

what can cause to it?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def print_users(user_dict, days):
  time = datetime.now()
  for key in user_dict:
      if time - timedelta(days=days) > user_dict[key]:
          print(key)

def run():
  users_dict = get_user_dict
  print_users(users_dict, args.days)
  print("Finish")

if __name__ =='__main__':
   run()
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, it *could* be a pycharm bug. Mine (2018.2) doesn't do it. Maybe try updating to the latest version?

Comment: most often this kind of issues come from a stale pyc file or an interpreter still running an outdated version of the module.

Comment: Side note: `time` is not a good variable name as it conflicts with a standard library module [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#module-time) and could cause accidental reassignment -> surprises.